# (SQLALCHEMY) : How to query a table to return items not present in another table (based on 7 values primary key)

Tags: python, sql, join, sqlalchemy

I have 2 tables, 1 of raw data (raw_data) and 1 of scores (score_dlhs). I want to query the raw data table to return only the items that are not already computed in the score table.

The primary key I need to base my query on is 7 fields composite-key. My knowledge of SQLAlchemy is still pretty basic, but I assume I can achieve this directly with a single query?

Here's what I have so far, but I am not sure my syntax is right :

```
result = session.query(raw_data, ().join(score_dlhs, (raw_data.distance!=score_dlhs.distance) &
                                                    (raw_data.width!=score_dlhs.width) & 
                                                    (raw_data.height!=score_dlhs.height) & 
                                                    (raw_data.setback!=score_dlhs.setback) & 
                                                    (raw_data.potence!=score_dlhs.potence) & 
                                                    (raw_data.manufacturier!=score_dlhs.manufacturier) & 
                                                    (raw_data.model!=score_dlhs.model)).all()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use left or right outer join, and then filter out those rows that have non-null values on the score table.

Something like this (i didn't test this! i just modified your query):

```
result = session.query(raw_data).outerjoin(score_dlhs, (raw_data.distance!=score_dlhs.distance) &
                                                (raw_data.width!=score_dlhs.width) & 
                                                (raw_data.height!=score_dlhs.height) & 
                                                (raw_data.setback!=score_dlhs.setback) & 
                                                (raw_data.potence!=score_dlhs.potence) & 
                                                (raw_data.manufacturier!=score_dlhs.manufacturier) & 
                                                (raw_data.model!=score_dlhs.model)).filter(score.width != None).all()
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution :

Python version :

```
      data_to_compute = (session.query(raw_data_uniformite_table).outerjoin(score_dlhs_table,(and_(score_dlhs_table.distance ==
                                                                                        raw_data_uniformite_table.distance, score_dlhs_table.largeur ==
                                                                                        raw_data_uniformite_table.largeur, score_dlhs_table.hauteur == raw_data_uniformite_table.hauteur,
                                                                                        score_dlhs_table.setback == raw_data_uniformite_table.setback, score_dlhs_table.potence ==
                                                                                        raw_data_uniformite_table.potence, score_dlhs_table.manufacturier == raw_data_uniformite_table.manufacturier,
                                                                                        score_dlhs_table.modele == raw_data_uniformite_table.modele))).filter(score_dlhs_table.distance == None)).all()
```